# How to convert Scalar Pyspark UDF to Pandas UDF?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF as below which is a normal scalar Pyspark UDF :

```
@udf()
def redact(colVal: column, offset: int = 0):
    if not colVal or not offset:
        return 'X'*8
    else:
        charList=list(colVal)
        charList[:-offset]='X'*(len(colVal)-offset)
        return "".join(charList)
```

While I try to convert this to pandas_udf as I read there is drastic performance inprovements in using vectorized UDF's in place of scalar UDF's, Im getting lot of issues related to pandas which Im less experienced in.

Please help me in converting this UDF to a Vectorized Pandas UDF

Answer (score 1):

The `redact` function can be wrapped inside a function that applies `redact` on each item of [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html).

> Currying needs to be applied since a scalar `offset` value is to be passed.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

def pandas_wrapper(values: pd.Series, offset: int) -> pd.Series:
    def redact(colVal: str, offset: int = 0):
        if not colVal or not offset:
            return 'X'*8
        else:
            charList=list(colVal)
            charList[:-offset]='X'*(len(colVal)-offset)
            return "".join(charList)
    return values.apply(lambda value: redact(value, offset))

def curried_wrapper(offset: int):
    return F.pandas_udf(lambda x: pandas_wrapper(x, offset), "string")

df = spark.createDataFrame([("abcdef", ), ("12yz", ), (None,)], ("data_col", ))

df.withColumn("redacted", curried_wrapper(2)(F.col("data_col"))).show()
```

### Output

```
+--------+--------+
|data_col|redacted|
+--------+--------+
|  abcdef|  XXXXef|
|    12yz|    XXyz|
|    null|XXXXXXXX|
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: wouldn't this defeat the purpose of using vectorized pandas udf (better performance by avoiding application of function at single row level), because it essentially is looping over all values (with `values.apply(lambda value: redact(value, offset))`?

Comment: Yes this is true, I don't attempt to vectorize the UDF here but present a way to invoke pandas UDF (with vectoized or non-vectorized implemenation). That said, using `pandas_udf` even with non-vectorized logic could give a boost in performance by overcoming the serialization overheads of non pandas UDF.

Answer (score 0):

A refactored version of Nithish's reply:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
from typing import Callable

def my_func(column_value: str) -> str:
    return column_value[:2] if column_value else None

def create_udf(f: Callable, *args, **kwargs):
    def pandas_wrapper(values: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
        return values.apply(f)

    return F.pandas_udf(pandas_wrapper, *args, **kwargs)

df = spark.createDataFrame([("abcdef", ), ("12yz", ), (None, )], ("data_col", ))

df.withColumn("my_func", F.udf(my_func, "string")(F.col("data_col"))) \
  .withColumn("my_func_pandas", create_udf(my_func, "string")(F.col("data_col"))).show()
```

The function can be anything, as long as it takes a single column.
So `create_udf` is a drop-in replacement for `F.udf` in this case.

As Nithish already pointed out, the serialization overhead is reduced, comparable to the parameter `useArrow=True` introduced in Spark 3.5.0.
So with Spark 3.5.0 this kind of code is no longer needed and useArrow can be used instead.