# Vectorized pandas udf in pyspark with dict lookup

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks

I'm trying to learn to use `pandas_udf` in pyspark (Databricks).

One of the assignments is to write a `pandas_udf` to sort by day of the week. I know how to do this using spark udf:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [('Sun', 282905.5), ('Mon', 238195.5), ('Thu', 264620.0), ('Sat', 278482.0), ('Wed', 227214.0)]
schema = 'day string, avg_users double'
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
print('Original')
df.show()


@udf()
def udf(day: str) -> str:
    dow = {"Mon": "1", "Tue": "2", "Wed": "3", "Thu": "4",
           "Fri": "5", "Sat": "6", "Sun": "7"}
    return dow[day] + '-' + day

print('with spark udf')
final_df = df.select(col('avg_users'), udf(col('day')).alias('day')).sort('day')
final_df.show()
```

Prints:

```
Original
+---+-----------+
|day|  avg_users|
+---+-----------+
|Sun|   282905.5|
|Mon|   238195.5|
|Thu|   264620.0|
|Sat|   278482.0|
|Wed|   227214.0|
+---+-----------+

with spark udf
+-----------+-----+
|  avg_users|  day|
+-----------+-----+
|   238195.5|1-Mon|
|   227214.0|3-Wed|
|   264620.0|4-Thu|
|   278482.0|6-Sat|
|   282905.5|7-Sun|
+-----------+-----+
```

Trying to do the same with `pandas_udf`

```
import pandas as pd


@pandas_udf('string')
def p_udf(day: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    dow = {"Mon": "1", "Tue": "2", "Wed": "3", "Thu": "4",
           "Fri": "5", "Sat": "6", "Sun": "7"}
    return dow[day.str] + '-' + day.str


p_final_df = df.select(df.avg_users, p_udf(df.day))

print('with pandas udf')
p_final_df.show()
```

I get `KeyError: <pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods object at 0x7f31197cd9a0>`. I think it's coming from `dow[day.str]`, which kinda makes sense.

I also tried:

```
return dow[day.str.__str__()] + '-' + day.str # KeyError: .... StringMethods
return dow[str(day.str)] + '-' + day.str      # KeyError: .... StringMethods
return dow[day.str.upper()] + '-' + day.str   # TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
return f"{dow[day.str]}-{day.str}"            # KeyError: .... StringMethods (but I think this is logically
                                              # wrong, returning a string instead of a Series)
```

I've read:

- [API reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html)
- [PySpark equivalent for lambda function in Pandas UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012580/pyspark-equivalent-for-lambda-function-in-pandas-udf)
- [How to convert Scalar Pyspark UDF to Pandas UDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711698/how-to-convert-scalar-pyspark-udf-to-pandas-udf)
- [Pandas UDF in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395846/pandas-udf-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `.str` method alone without any actual vectorized transformation was giving you the error. Also, you can not use the whole series as a key for your `dow` dict. Use a `map` method for `pandas.Series`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pandas as pd

data = [('Sun', 282905.5), ('Mon', 238195.5), ('Thu', 264620.0), ('Sat', 278482.0), ('Wed', 227214.0)]
schema = 'day string, avg_users double'
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

@pandas_udf("string")
def p_udf(day: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    dow = {"Mon": "1", "Tue": "2", "Wed": "3", "Thu": "4",
           "Fri": "5", "Sat": "6", "Sun": "7"}
    return day.map(dow) + '-' + day

df.select(df.avg_users, p_udf(df.day).alias("day")).show()

+---------+-----+
|avg_users|  day|
+---------+-----+
| 282905.5|7-Sun|
| 238195.5|1-Mon|
| 264620.0|4-Thu|
| 278482.0|6-Sat|
| 227214.0|3-Wed|
+---------+-----+
```

Comment: could you recommend some tutorial/docs that can teach about this? most docs/blogs I saw, take very elementary usecases and explains the very basics only.

Comment: @Kashyap I haven't seen good tutorials on these topics too. I generally refer to Databricks documentation for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! Pandas' API reference seems decent enough. [This](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) and [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html).

Answer (score 1):

what about we return a dataframe using [groupeddata](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas) and orderby after you do the udf. Pandas `sort_values` is quite problematic within udfs.

Basically, in the udf I generate the numbers using python and then concatenate them back to the day column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import calendar
def sortdf(pdf):
  day=pdf.day
  pdf =pdf.assign(day=(day.map(dict(zip(calendar.day_abbr, range(7))))+1).astype(str) + '-'+day)
 
  return pdf

df.groupby('avg_users').applyInPandas(sortdf, schema=df.schema).show()

+-----+---------+
|  day|avg_users|
+-----+---------+
|3-Wed| 227214.0|
|1-Mon| 238195.5|
|4-Thu| 264620.0|
|6-Sat| 278482.0|
|7-Sun| 282905.5|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: where do you use `pandas_udf`? Is there a Pandas UDF here? Or is this a different way of sorting by day?

Comment: This is a pandas udf, check the reference

Comment: So in this case function doesn't need to be annotated?