# databricks - how to debug parameters when calling function

Tags: python, tags, databricks

In databricks, I have 2 notebooks.  One notebooks holds a function.  The other notebook calls the function in the first notebook.

this is how I am calling the function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    df_adatposUpload = joined_df.select(
          ,'PATBKG'
          ,varMyBloombergFunction(col('pctym'), col('ExchCode'), col('BBSymbol'), col('BBYellow'), col('OptCode'), col('YearDigits'), col('WeeklyOptions'), col('psubty'), col('pstrik'), col('admmultstrike')).alias('BBSymbol')
    )
```

I am receiving a long error, but bottom line it says something about line 58 in the function.

```
PythonException: 'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()', from <command-2467610093078830>, line 58
```

the line is

```
if len(BBSymbol) == 1:
```

I think for this particular case is BBsymbol is blank or NULL

Is there a way to run some kind of debugger where it shows me all the values that are being fed into the function?  There are ten parameters for each row of data.

this is how I create the function in the first notebook

```
def CreateBloombergSymbol(pctym,ExchCode, BBSymbol, BBYellow, OptCode, YearDigits, WeeklyOptions, psubty, pstrik, admmultstrike):
    
    digitMonth = pctym[4:6]
    digitYear1 = pctym[3:4]
    digitYear2 = pctym[2:4]
    
    match_dict = {
        "01": "F",
        "02": "G",
        "03": "H",
        "04": "J",
        "05": "K",
        "06": "M",
        "07": "N",
        "08": "Q",
        "09": "U",
        "10": "V",
        "11": "X",
        "12": "Z",
        "foo": "missingValue"
    }
    charMonth = match_dict.get(digitMonth, "foo")
```

Comment: Can you provide the function called varMyBloombergFunction? are you using PySpark APIs to define it or pure python functions?

Comment: thanks... have databricks set to python.  I updated code above to show how I start the function

Comment: I am trying to see the parameters that crashed the function

Comment: you have to use User Defined Functions (UDFs) to convert the Python function to a Pyspark function, refer:  https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/  and https://walkenho.github.io/how-to-convert-python-functions-into-pyspark-UDFs/

Comment: I followed the example in the first link and added a print() statement to function.  "print() runs inside each executor, so the diagnostic logs also go into the executors’ stdout instead of the driver stdout, which can be accessed under the Executors tab in Spark Web UI. If you are in local mode, you can find the URL for the Web UI by running" ... where can I look at the stdout results?.  when I try running the URL I just get an error "this site can't be reached"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UDFs are run on workers, so putting `print()` won't help much. Easiest thing to do to debug is just return your debug message from function as a column. E.g.

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1, 2), (11, 22)], schema=['a', 'b'] )
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |2  |
|11 |22 |
+---+---+

>>> 
>>> @F.udf(returnType=StructType([StructField('val', IntegerType()), StructField('log', StringType())]))
... def my_func(a, b):
...   return a * b, f'got a: {a}, b: {b}. Returning: {a * b}'
... 
>>> 
>>> df.withColumn('c', my_func('a', 'b')).show(truncate=False)
+---+---+---------------------------------------+
|a  |b  |c                                      |
+---+---+---------------------------------------+
|1  |2  |{2, got a: 1, b: 2. Returning: 2}      |
|11 |22 |{242, got a: 11, b: 22. Returning: 242}|
+---+---+---------------------------------------+
>>> 
>>> df.withColumn('c', my_func('a', 'b')).select('a', 'b', 'c.*').show(truncate=False)
+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
|a  |b  |val|log                             |
+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |2  |2  |got a: 1, b: 2. Returning: 2    |
|11 |22 |242|got a: 11, b: 22. Returning: 242|
+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
>>>
```

Note that this is a bad idea in production code from performance pov.

---

Also checkout: [Vectorized pandas udf in pyspark with dict lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71533765/vectorized-pandas-udf-in-pyspark-with-dict-lookup)

Comment: thank you @Kashyap, quick question. if an error gets generated in the function, say for example a string is entered instead of a integer as specified.  I'm assuming nothing will be returned and a error will occur.  And it will not tell me the parameters that crashed the function correct?

Comment: @solarissf, correct. You can put a catch-all (`except BaseException as be`) inside the UDF for debugging and return the exception message in log message if an exception is thrown.